# How to show the posts of some category first, and then the rest? Cant figure out the coding

Tags: categories

but to be specific, i need to retrieve certain data from the post - and showed one category's post datas first (preference) in the coupon's list and then other categories post data second in the list.

I meant to say that suppose first 6 coupons are first preference, then it will be shown first then the rest. And then goes the pagination. Therefore as, @Swopnil Dangol suggested, i try to use the 2 LOOPS for (one category & rest of the category respectively.

But the problem is even i click the second page, it is showing the first page data, not the rest of the datas. Thanx in advance. I try to find answers through the internet no success, plz help.

```
<?php 
            $args = array();
            $args['post_type'] = 'coupons';
            $args['cat'] = 20;
            $query1 = new WP_Query($args);      

            while($query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post();
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
            $discount = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_discount', true);
            $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_date', true);
            $code = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_code', true);
            $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_url', true);   
            $daysleft = round( ($date-time()) / 24 / 60 / 60);  
        ?>
        <div class="coupon">
            <?php if($thumb != '') { ?>
                <div class="coupon-top">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo aq_resize($thumb, 300, 200, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"></a>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="coupon-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php truncate_title(15);?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="coupon-bottom">
                <div class="coupon-offer">
                    <?php echo  substr($discount, 0, 15);?>
                </div>
                <div class="coupon-date">
                    <?php
                        if($date == '')_e('Хүчинтэй', 'Couponize');
                        else if($daysleft <= 0) _e('Дууссан', 'Couponize'); 
                        else echo sprintf( _n('%d day left.', '%d Хоног Үлдсэн.', $daysleft, 'Couponize'), $daysleft ); 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();?>


        <?php 
            $args = array( 'category__not_in' => array(20));
            $args['post_type'] = 'coupons';
            $query2 = new WP_Query($args);

            while($query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post();
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
            $discount = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_discount', true);
            $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_date', true);
            $code = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_code', true);
            $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_url', true);   
            $daysleft = round( ($date-time()) / 24 / 60 / 60);  
        ?>
        <div class="coupon">
            <?php if($thumb != '') { ?>
                <div class="coupon-top">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo aq_resize($thumb, 300, 200, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"></a>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="coupon-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php truncate_title(15);?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="coupon-bottom">
                <div class="coupon-offer">
                    <?php echo  substr($discount, 0, 15);?>
                </div>
                <div class="coupon-date">
                    <?php
                        if($date == '')_e('Хүчинтэй', 'Couponize');
                        else if($daysleft <= 0) _e('Дууссан', 'Couponize'); 
                        else echo sprintf( _n('%d day left.', '%d Хоног Үлдсэн.', $daysleft, 'Couponize'), $daysleft ); 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 different loops: 1 for some of your categories and another for the rest.

```
//Here 2,6 are the category ids
$query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
// The Loop
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    $query1->the_post();
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
// The Loop
while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->the_post();
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Use this code on the page where you would like to show your category posts. If your're new to this,maybe you should first know about [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to figure out which page is being loaded and in which file you should place your code.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion, can you kindly tell me where i should put this statement? thanx in advance, plz bear with me, i am new to this.

Comment: Ive edited the answer, you can check it out

Comment: hi thanx for the suggestion. I used two different loops and it is not showing the expected result, can you kindly tell me where I am missing, plz refer to more detailed info from the below answer. thanks again. can you plz look through the code and where i am missing.